# Modelling latent online shopping states from e-commerce website clickstream data - What type of method to use?

Tags: classification, clustering, k-means

I am new to Data Science but really enthusiastic about it. Really appreciate communities like this one, so thanks in anticipation.

I entered a competition to solve a data mining challenge for an e-commerce website. The challenge is as follows:

> Build a model based on clickstream data, to detect the phase of the
>   customer in the customer journey (or related intent of customer).

We are not given specific definitions of the customer phases, instead we are supposed to come up with them ourselves based on observable behaviours of users (and maybe academic literature). I believe there are three main shopping states:

1. Directed buyers - Goal oriented, specific product in mind.
2. Deliberate searchers - Know the basic category, but not a specific product in mind.
3. Hedonic browsers - Similar to window shoppers in real life.

After cleaning up the data, I have a table with session-level summary variables such as:

- Category breadth: How many unique categories a user visited in a given session
- Product to category ratio: Time spent in category pages vs product pages
- Session source: (Direct, Search Engine, Social media, Referral)
- Added item to cart: Yes/No
- Ordered item: Yes/No
- etc

I have the raw analytics export data (you can see all variables in the IBM source bellow), so can basically make any other variables I want. But thought these are good enough to explain myself.

**My question is:**

What method would you use in order to come up with Latent Shopping States for these users? Preferably I would like to obtain the probability that each individual user is in a specific shopping state. As well as some sort of weight for the factors that compose each state (e.g. Directed shoppers have a very high Category Breadth)

Initially I thought some sort of clustering algorithm such as K-Means, but that does not give me probabilities. I am now leaning towards Latent Class Analysis, but its still a bit abstract to me.

If I can provide you with any additional information let me know!

Thanks,

Sources:

- Ramachandran, Vandana; Viswanathan, Siva; and Lucas, Hank, "STATE OF
  SHOPPING AND THE VALUE OF INFORMATION: INSIGHTS FROM THE CLICKSTREAM"
  (2010). ICIS 2010 - http://aisel.aisnet.org/icis2010_submissions/254/
- IBM Digital Analytics Export info - http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPG9M/Export/Export/digitaldatafeed.html